# Making QGIS select correct feature id in PostGIS materialized view?

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.2

Can you tell me if there is a way to make QGIS automatically select the correct feature ID when I choose a materialized view in PostGIS?

It's not a big deal, but it is nonetheless something I would like to avoid. I tried to create an unique index on the fid column, but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Could you add version of QGIS / PostGIS / OS to the original question please?
I've had a problem like this with views in QGIS 2.12 but it disappeared with 2.14. No problems since (current version 2.16.2). Would like to know why as well...

Comment: I am using the latest (2.16.2) version. The same is used in a couple of other machines (different environment and OS) and all have the same issue. Could it be a PostGIS issue? I mean something missing in my materialized view (other than query and unique index definition ?)